# Cómo obtener un tag específico de un xml con python

Tags: python, xml

tengo un problema y lo simplifiqué así:
Tengo 5 tags con el nombre: "outline", unas están más anidadas que otras y todas tienen el atributo 'text'.
Sucede que con mi código he logrado capturar los valores de 'text' pero de todas los "outline" e incluso de los "outline" más anidados, pero yo solo quiero de los "outline" más cercanos a la raíz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el código que estoy usando:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('podcasts.opml.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
nodos = root.findall('.//body//outline')

for node in nodos:
    texto = node.attrib.get('text')
    print(texto)
```

Esta es la salida:
Non-tech
99% Invisible
Python
Talk Python to Me
Podcast.**init**
Pero yo solo necesito: Non-tech Python

Comment: Publicar el XML como texto ayudaría bastante a encontrar una solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que veo es que usas esto: `nodos = root.findall('.//body//outline')`
Cuando navegas un xml `//` implica que puede saltar cuantos nodos intermedios hagan falta,
sustituyendo esa línea por `nodos = root.findall('.//body/outline')` debería darte solo los que cuelgan directamente de body

Comment: Hola Benito, muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho. Te cuento que el problema que subí era una simplificación, mi problema real es algo más complejo: de forma similar al nodo de nombre "outline" tengo un xml con un nodo llamado `cbc:id` , pero el código python
`nodos = root.findall('./cbc:ID')`
me bota el error: prefix 'cbc' not found in prefix map
Pareciera que trata de leer a "cbc" como un prefijo o un comando, cuando en realidad el nombre de mi nodo.
¿Sabes cómo podría solucionar esto?